# Faraday's law conditions

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

Does Faraday's law only apply when there is a changing B field or change in area for a closed loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both.

The equation $\mathscr E =\ – \frac{d\Phi}{dt}$ embodies the Faraday law (and, by means of the minus sign, Lenz's law). It can be used when $\Phi$ changes due to change in flux density over a stationary loop **or** due to the loop area changing (motional emf).

In the first case the emf is due to an electric field accompanying a changing magnetic field, in accordance with the Faraday-Maxwell equation $$\text{curl} \vec E= -\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t}.$$

In the second case the emf arises from magnetic Lorentz forces acting on the charge carriers in the moving parts of the loop.

Faraday's law covers both cases.

Comment: Ok thanks so in a  rod moving through a constant B field, we can't use Faradays law because it's not a loop?

Comment: You could have the rod sliding on stationary metal rails joined by a resistor at one end so that the rod, rails and resistor from a loop. Then you could apply Faraday's law. For the rod moving by itself in a magnetic field there is still an emf, $(\vec v \times \vec B).\vec l= (\vec l \times \vec v).\vec B$ due to the action of the magnetic Lorentz force on the charge carriers. This is arguably a more basic way of calculating the motional emf than using Faraday's law. You could still, though, *imagine* the rod to be part of a loop, and use Faraday's law.